# The sort method does nothing, and the state remains the same

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I want to sort array of objects in desc by id.** 
No errors in console.

*After calling the sort method, nothing changes for the state allPosts*

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'

export const Home = () => {

    const [allPosts, setAllPosts] = useState([ // here array of objects])

    const sort = () => {
        setAllPosts(allPosts.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id))
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <Button onClick={sort}>Sort</Button>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Array sort is _in-place_, which means React doesn't know the array has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.sort` doesn't create a new array reference, which isn't working well with react

Try this:

```
setAllPosts([...allPosts].sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id))
```